# Dart :: Process.run() get stdout as stream instead of String, just like Process.start()

Tags: dart

I want to execute some processes one by one in dart using either [`Process.run()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-io/Process/run.html) or [`Process.start()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-io/Process/start.html)

And I want to show the verbose log of the process. But the problem is Whenever I am using `run` it's providing the stdout in a string i.e., at the end of the process completion. But I want to display the logs while the process is being executed.

Cause `run` is returning us the instance of `ProcessResult` instead of `Process`, the returned stdout is String.

Have to use `stdout.write(cleanProcess.stdout);` in case of `run`;

**OR**

Now in case `start()`, I am getting stdout as Stream which is desired but the only problem is the `start` returns us to the `Process` and Doesn't actually `await` for the Process to complete.

Can use `stdout.addStream(buildProcess.stdout);` to display stdout as stream

---

Code that I am trying to execute, and display the verbose.

```dart
    print("HighSupply Executor : flutter clean");
    var cleanProcess = await Process.run('flutter', ["clean", "--verbose"],
        workingDirectory: "${flutterFolder.path}");
    stdout.write(cleanProcess.stdout); //only getting stdout in one go. needed as stream.

    print("HighSupply Executor : flutter pub get");
    var pubGetProcess = await Process.run('flutter', //OR can we use start and wait for process to complete
        ["pub", "get", "--verbose"],
        workingDirectory: "${flutterFolder.path}");
    stdout.write(pubGetProcess.stdout);

    print("HighSupply Executor : flutter build apk");
    var buildProcess = await Process.run(
        'flutter', ["build", "apk", "--verbose", generatedParams],
        workingDirectory: "${flutterFolder.path}");
    stdout.write(buildProcess.stdout);
```

---

**TL;DR**

Can I anyhow get stdout as a stream in case `Prcocess.run()` OR Can we wait for Process to complete before executing another in case of `Process.start()`

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit: 1**

As @julemand101 suggested to use [exitcode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-io/Process/exitCode.html) and wait for it to return after the process completion, It works fine with my case, and haven't run into any issue yet but As he mentioned and stated in docs that is not reliable, so we are looking for a better concrete solution for it.

Comment: I deleted my comment since it is a little more complicated. If you read the documentation for `exitCode` you can see at the bottom: "There is no guarantee that stdout and stderr have finished reporting the buffered output of the process when the returned future completes. To be sure that all output is captured, wait for the done event on the streams."

Comment: Since I don't really have the time right now to make a bulletproof solution, I just ended up deleting my comment. :)

Comment: No problem, Thanks for the help anyways. For now It's working for me but let's wait for the concrete solution or more input if anyone have.

Comment: @julemand101 can you share the solution with me as well. I am looking for a way to stream logs during runtime of a process as well. I am executing a test suite using process.run, and I have to wait 3 hours before I can see the whole output :(

Comment: @AyushMandowara Please make a question for your problem with details about your problem, expected result and a minimal example which reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 10):

Source: [Process](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-io/Process-class.html)

`Process.start()` is used to interact with the code. The future gives us a Process, after it has finished starting, but the Process is still running when we have the Process.

> When the future completes the process is started and your code can interact with the process: writing to stdin, listening to stdout, and so on

Now we can access a Stream of integers as `Process.stdout` and parse it with a utf8 decoder.

Sample code:

```
main() async {
  var process = await Process.start('cat', []);
  process.stdout
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .forEach(print);
  process.stdin.writeln('Hello, world!');
  process.stdin.writeln('Hello, galaxy!');
  process.stdin.writeln('Hello, universe!');
}
```

Out of the scope of this answer, we can manipulate the process objects, send interrupts, kill etc. and when the process ends, expect to get a done event on the stream.

Comment: This is making same behaviour using `stdout.addStream(buildProcess.stdout)`. I some how want to either wait for the previous process to complete or show verbose during the process in case of '`run`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is too late, but I will leave it here maybe someone will find it helpful;

After playing around with the `Process` `start()` and `run()` methods, I found a way to achieve the required behavior of the original question by `await`ing for `addStream` `Future` to complete.

```
void main() async {
  final p = await Process.start('bash', ['-c', 'sleep 3']);
  await stdout.addStream(p.stdout);
  print('the end ');
}
```